aws amplify production error for next js app: Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information)
in console got this error:
An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.
same app is working on vercel but not on aws amplify.
using mongo atlas as database and prisma.
below is build cmd of aws amplify
version: 1
frontend:
phases:
preBuild:
commands:
- npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
build:
commands:
- env | grep -e DATABASE_URL -e GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID -e GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET -e NEXTAUTH_SECRET -e NEXTAUTH_URL >> .env.production
- npm run build
artifacts:
baseDirectory: .next
files:
- '/*'
cache:
paths:
- .next/cache//*
- .npm/**/*
not sure why isn't working, tried everything
